# How to create a text editor that can "run Java code" in an application?

Tags: java

This is the prototype of my project

[image]

Is there a pre-built Java text editor that I can embed so that the syntax will be just like Java?

Comment: @user2864740 yes sir, if possible.

Comment: Short answer: no, but there may be some 3rd party libraries that provide the required functionality (eg. is Beanshell still around/relevant?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) you can embed different scripting languages in your application, including [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html) which is based on Java.

Check [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) and [Where can I find a list of available JSR-223 scripting languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838369/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-available-jsr-223-scripting-languages) for more information.