# HP True Client replacement

Tags: loadrunner

Dear HP Load Runner gurus!

We find the HP Load Runner True Client not very stable and forces us to using old version of Firefox. We need to test against the latest version Firefox due to application requirements. We have tested a few versions including 12.53. It is also quite heavy on the CPU% . we get about 1:1 relation between [user]:[cpu]  when True Client is used.

We want to drive the GUI in these load tests. We do not want to drive/navigate the load test by sending HTTP requests, i.e. not driving the browser.

Could you recommend  alternatives;

1. Plugins to HP True Client  (driver) ,maybe someone else have
   developed a similar plugin that HP LoadRunner can hook into?
2. A good alternative to HP Load Runner that also opens the end-users browser GUI for load testing, that scales well? Preferably Opensource.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> We want to drive the GUI in these load tests. We do not want to
>   drive/navigate the load test by sending HTTP requests, i.e. not
>   driving the browser.

What is the technical reason driving this?  How does your server know that a GUI is required for proper operation?  This was state of the art in 1995/96, but there are very sound technical reasons for server performance testing that the entire market made the move to API level virtual users.

If you suggest that "rendering" is the reason for this, then I would suggest that you carefully examine the developer tools of your browser to answer your questions about how much time is being spent inside of the browser.  This is a question which should be asked and addressed at every level prior to server performance testing with every developer and every functional validation of the GUI.

If you suggest that we need to understand this under load, then I would suggest that a path has been available for twenty years to do this.  One:  Implement the majority of your load as API layer virtual users.  Take one virtual user per business process and implement this as a GUI virtual user, which runs the full browser in a distinct operating system instance.   Name your transactions appropriately, such as Login_HTTP and Login_GUI.  The difference between them at a given load point represents the overhead in your client.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which is free and open source. You should be able to use [WebDriver Sampler plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which provides JMeter and [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) integration.

Alternatively you can plug in [Selenium Java client](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/java/client) libraries and write the code to drive the browser instance(s) using one of the following approaches:

- [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which allows executing arbitrary Java/Groovy code (other languages are [supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838369/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-available-jsr-223-scripting-languages) but not recommended)
- [JUnit Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/junitsampler_tutorial.html) - if you have existing Selenium tests you can even import them this way
- More "hardcore" options exist as well like implementing a [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler or even a writing a new [JMeter Plugin](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)